# Is Nyāya Sūtras an authentic Hindu text to use in our main site?

Tags: discussion

In Hinduism stack exchange, is it allowed to cite or ask or answer any thing related to [Nyāya Sūtras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ny%C4%81ya_S%C5%ABtras) by Akṣapāda Gautama?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: Yes most certainly allowed to cite etc .. it is one of the 6 Hindu Darshanas .. See [this](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=576) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy)

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury because of I  don't know whether he is sage, Rishi etc., or not...

Comment: I think "Is Nyaya Sutras an authentic Hindu text?" is question belongs to main site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nyaya sutras by Gautama are one of foundational texts of Nyaya, one of the shad darshanas. Just like Brahma Sutras are for Vedanta, it is foundational text for Nyaya philosophy. So, we can cite it without any doubt.

It is an authentic work while answering questions about Nyaya philosophy.

Comment: I think while answering via app, you mistakenly distorted the spelling of philosophy as well.

Comment: You can always correct it ;-)